# Angle between two 2d vectors, diff between two methods?

Tags: c#, vector, trigonometry

I've got this code snippet, and I'm wondering why the results of the first method differ from the results of the second method, given the same input?

```
public double AngleBetween_1(vector a, vector b) {
  var dotProd = a.Dot(b);
  var lenProd = a.Len*b.Len;
  var divOperation = dotProd/lenProd;
  return Math.Acos(divOperation) * (180.0 / Math.PI);
}

public double AngleBetween_2(vector a, vector b) {
  var dotProd = a.Dot(b);
  var lenProd = a.Len*b.Len;
  var divOperation = dotProd/lenProd;
  return (1/Math.Cos(divOperation)) * (180.0 / Math.PI);
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's because the first method is correct, while the second method is incorrect.

You may notice that the arccosine function is sometimes written "acos" and sometimes written "cos<sup>-1</sup>".  This is a quirk of mathematical notation: "cos<sup>-1</sup>" is really the arccosine and NOT the reciprocal of the cosine (which is the secant).

However, if you ever see "cos<sup>2</sup>", then that's the square of the cosine, and "cos<sup>3</sup>" is the cube of the cosine.  The notation for trigonometric functions is weird this way.  Most operators use superscripts to indicate repeated application.

Comment: Fore sure.  Thanks!  Its been a while since I took trig in highschool.

Answer (score 5):

`Math.Acos(divOperation)` isn't equivalent to `1/Math.Cos(divOperation)`. [arccos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_function) is the [inverse function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) of cos, not the multiplicative inverse.

Answer (score 3):

Probably because acos(x) ≠ 1/cos(x).